# Importing certain table columns into database table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a new database table called `schools`. I have an existing database table on another server that has similar school info that I need. Example: Name, City, State etc., I am using phpMyAdmin to manage this.

My question is... What is the best/detailed way to export the school data from the outside server's database table into the new database table but only extracting and imported the columns I need (example: Name, City, State, etc)?

Comment: Do you have access to the command-line (or at least the mysql client programs) on both servers?

Comment: liquorvicar - if you are talking about phpmyadmin access on both servers then yes I do

Comment: How big is the table you want to export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, select the data you need,

```
SELECT (name, city, state) FROM schools
```

Then in PHP, output it to some format,

```
$results = $query->fetchAll();
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($results); $i++) {
    # format the output
}
```

phpMyAdmin has functions to import (and export) data in certain formats including CSV.

You can then import the CSV file to the new server.

You could also do it the other way: save the whole database and import it to the new server. Then delete the columns you dont need with SQL following this syntax,

```
ALTER TABLE tableName DROP columnName;
```

Comment: I guess I could also import the school info from the other server into a new temporary table and then take whatever information from that table and insert into the new columns on the new school table right?

Comment: Boat floats on path of least resistance :) Thanks Ozzy

Comment: @Ozzy Why would you want to either create your own code to export the data, or export it in csv format when phpMyAdmin has perfectly good ways of exporting pure (My)SQL?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using phpMyAdmin then it allows you to export a whole table in SQL format to a downloadable file. That would seem to be the best way to export the data. You can then upload this file to the destination server and import it via phpMyAdmin.

One caveat with this method is that you need to make sure your table names don't clash. If they do, you will need to rename one or the other (I'd suggest renaming the source table before you export it).

Once you've imported the whole table you can do an INSERT INTO...SELECT on the required fields.

Comment: Is this kinda what I said under Ozzy's Comment?

Comment: @Joe Yes, I hadn't seen that comment.